# is it possible to integrate GCP Secrets manager with Anthos?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cicd

while using cloud build for CI/CD for Anthos, wanted to know if it was possible to integrate Secrets Manager with Anthos . Are there any links or documents which convey such examples ?

Comment: Have you read https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager ?

Comment: I see a reference of using the secret manager with Cloud Run , but did not see any integration with Anthos.